# Why is Double-entry Bookkeeping always equal? (Part 2)

Tags: banking, money-supply

In this [question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/6460/5780), with answer here [Destroying the Dollar](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/6460/5780)hypothetically a hack is used to trick whatever programme is used to make sure accounts balance, so say a transfer is made from Bank manager A to Hacker's B account, the value of said transfer is deposited into B's account but when it is to be subtracted from A's account the hack tricks the bank programme to think the transaction bounced and so the amount is deposited back into A's account but is *not* reduced by B's account.  Would this be possible.  And if so, would this create wealth out of nothing, and assuming the hacker will go on to spend this money in the economy raise GDP?